# storing compiled python 3.7 regular expressions in a database

Tags: python-3.x, regex, postgresql

I'm using AWS lambda for some text mining tasks in a severless environment. Since it is serverless there is no possibility to keep the running environment running and starting it cold takes like 10 minutes to compile all the regular expressions.
Therefore I would love to store a bunch (more than 10k) of serialized compiled regular expressions in a Database to fast reuse them when needed.
Does anyone have any pointers for me?

Something along the lines of:

```
import psycopg2
import re

r=re.compile(r"\w+") 
cursor.execute("update regex set compiled=%s where id=%s", (r, 1))
```

with 'compiled' being of type bytea and

```
cursor.execute("select compiled from regex where id=%s", (1,))
r=cursor.fetchone()[0]
r.search("somestring")
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "*compiled regular expression*"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*>10k [..] regular expressions*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is running into the same Problem, the solution is to prevent cold-starts of the lambda.
Far from elegant, but currently the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about storing the returned object in re.compile(r"\w+").

You can store the string r"\w+" in NoSQL database like DynamoDB and retrieve the string to compile it using re.compile.

Like this:

```
cursor.execute("select compiled from regex where id=%s", (1,))
s=cursor.fetchone()[0]
r=re.compile(s)
r.search("somestring")
...
```

Another option is to use Python Pickle to serialize your object, but I think that it's not possible to save it in Database, and you can use S3 to upload the pickle resulting file and retrieve it.

With Lambda warm start, you could keep this object in memory using Pickle + S3 whenever you need but the first executions will have high latency.

Comment: storing the pickle in the DB would be possible, but as far as my tests got me, pickle doesn't store the compiled bits :-/ it just stores the string, so it didn't speed anything up

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to this is not use a serverless architecture in situations where it is ineffective.

Python does not seem to offer a way an efficient way to serialize compiled regex.  All you get out is the code needed to recompile it.

Comment: I feared as much, even marshal does not help to get the compiled regex stored. So I actually might have to use an EC2.